# How to run following Matlab code using GPU?

Tags: matlab, gpu

I want to run the Matlab code through GPU, How may I convert the following code so that it can access the GPU?

I have tried to convert it but I am getting the object instances when I am using gpuarray in syntax not getting the data.

how to resolve this problem?
If possible please convert the following code.

```
path1 = 'C:\Data\For new Paper3\TUM_GAID_Gait_Analysis\AEI_PEI\';
list1 = dir(path1);                       
fName1 = {list1.name};
[~,y1] = size(fName1);

cv111=[];

for f_no=3:y1
    path2 = char(strcat(path1,fName1(f_no),'\'));
    list2 = dir(path2);                       
    fName2 = {list2.name};
    [~,y2] = size(fName2);
    fName1(f_no)
    path2
    y2
    numberOfPose=0;
    for ff_no=3:3
        path3 = char(strcat(path2,fName2(ff_no),'\'));
        list3 = dir(path3);                       
        fName3 = {list3.name};
        [~,y3] = size(fName3);
        numberOfPose = (y3-2)/10;        
    end 
    cv11=[];
    for num=1:numberOfPose
        train = double([]);
        group1 = cell(1,1);
        group2 = cell(1,1);
        for ff_no=3:y2
            path3 = char(strcat(path2,fName2(ff_no),'\'));
            list3 = dir(path3);                       
            fName3 = {list3.name};
            [~,y3] = size(fName3);
            for fff_no=2+(num)
                group1{1} = [group1{1},(ff_no-2),(ff_no-2)];
                path4 = char(strcat(path3,fName3(fff_no)));              
                image = double(imread(path4));
                temp1=image(:);
                train=[train; temp1';temp1'];
            end   
        end  

        [coeff,score,~,~,explained] = pca(train);            
        sm = 0;
        no_components = 0;
        for k = 1:size(explained,1)
            sm = sm+explained(k);
            if sm <= 99.4029
               no_components= no_components+1;
            end
        end
        m = mean(train,1);
        mat1 = score(:,1:no_components);  
        cv1=[];        
        num
        for ff_no=3:y2
            path3 = char(strcat(path2,fName2(ff_no),'\'));
            list3 = dir(path3);                       
            fName3 = {list3.name};
            [~,y3] = size(fName3);
            for fff_no=numberOfPose*1+2+(num)
                group2{1} = [group2{1},(ff_no-2)];
                path4 = char(strcat(path3,fName3(fff_no)));
                image = double(imread(path4));
                Img_mean = double(image(:)')-m;
                Img_proj = Img_mean*coeff;
                test=Img_proj(:,1:no_components);
                prob1=double([]);
                [x,y]=size(train);
                class = classify(test,mat1,group1{1},'diaglinear');
                cv1=[cv1;class];                
            end   
        end      
        cv11=[cv11,cv1];             
    end
    cv111=[cv111,cv11];
end
```

Comment: Not a single one of these loops can run on the GPU, because your file access is mixed throughout the code, and the GPU has no filesystem.  If you refactor to separate file access and computation, you may be able to move the computation to a GPU.

Comment: ok, I will try to modified it